# Why reading of excel file does not works with Crealytics version spark-excel_2.12-3.5.0_0.20.1

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, databricks, pyspark-pandas

I could able to read the Excel file data using Crealytics library spark-excel_2.12-3.4.1_0.19.0 but was not able to execute the same code by using the latest version spark-excel_2.12-3.5.0_0.20.1.

I tried the below code but none of the code works with latest library spark-excel_2.12-3.5.0_0.20.1.

```
df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("inferschema",True).option("header", True).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true").option("keepUndefinedRows", True).option("dataAddress","'SHEET_NAME'!").load(path)
   
df=spark.read.format("excel").option("inferschema",True).option("header", True).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true").option("keepUndefinedRows", True).option("dataAddress","'SHEET_NAME'!").load(path)
```

It is throwing follwoing error when used latest Crealytics

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o412.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: excel. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:744)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:794)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:237)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: excel.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:730)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:730)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:730)
    ... 15 more
```

Note that,Executing the above code in Databrciks Python cell with scala version 2.x

My question here is why it is not working when upgraded to latest version of crealytics?

Comment: What Databricks runtime do you use? Are you using Unity Catalog Shared cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time here. I found that there is an issue with library and it was reported. Here is the link for the same

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/789